# ¿Como pasar como parámetro una conexión PDO a función usando SOAP en PHP?

Tags: php

Poseo un web service que utiliza `SOAP`, este posee un metodo llamado `muestraPersonas` el cual debería retornar una lista de datos de una base de datos `MySQL`, usando `PDO`.

Aqui los archivos del proyecto:

**conexion.php**

```
<?php
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$db   = 'test';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$charset = 'utf8';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$opt = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
```

**soap_conexion.php**

```
<?php
require_once "lib/nusoap.php";
require_once "conexion.php";

function muestraPersonas($pdo) {
   $consulta = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM personas");
   $resultado = $consulta -> fetchAll();
   return $resultado;
}

if(!isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA)) {
$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = file_get_contents("php://input");
}
$server = new soap_server();
$server->register("muestraPersonas");
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
```

**cliente.php**

```
<?php
require_once "lib/nusoap.php";
require_once "conexion.php";

$cliente = new nusoap_client("http://localhost/WebService/soap_conexion.php");

$resultado = $cliente->call("muestraPersonas");
foreach ($resultado as $valor) {
    echo $valor["dni_persona"]."<br>";
    echo $valor["nombre_persona"]."<br>";
    echo $valor["apellido_persona"]."<br>";
}
```

> **El problema**: No se de que manera pasarle `$pdo` a la funcion de `muestraPersonas`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quizás no la mejor manera, pero funcionará:

```
function muestraPersonas() {

   global $pdo; // <-- Añadir aquí

   $consulta = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM personas");
   $resultado = $consulta -> fetchAll();
   return $resultado;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Tras investigar (solo un poco) *creo* que puedes pasar los parámetros de esta manera:

```
$resultado = $cliente->call("muestraPersonas", array('pdo' => $pdo ) );
```

Comment: ¿cual seria la mejor practica?

Comment: @Victor-Random - He actualizado la respuesta... tras investigar un poco he encontrado que puedes pasar los parámetros como array... pero no lo puedo testear ni tengo experiencia con SOAP... saludos